# Installing a CRAN package for R language

Tags: r, cran

I would like to install the following package for R,

> https://thlfi.github.io/read.gt3x/index.html

When I run this command on the R command line, I get the following message,

> remotes::install_github("THLfi/read.gt3x")
> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘remotes’

Comment: First run `install.packages('remotes')`

Comment: Since the package is on CRAN, did you try `install.packages("PhysicalActivity")`? That's how you install CRAN packages. Where did you get that other command from?

Comment: I got the command from the link in my question.

Comment: After intalling remotes and PhysicalActivity, I get this message now: ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘read.gt3x

Comment: Run `install.packages('Rcpp')`

Comment: I don't understand. The code `remotes::install_github("THLfi/read.gt3x")` is not listed in the link you provided (https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/PhysicalActivity/html/queryActigraph.html)

Comment: Apologies, updated my question.

Comment: The updated link is NOT a CRAN package. R doesn't have a built in feature for installing from github. You need to use an additional package like `remotes` to help with that. You also need to set up a bunch of thing to be able to install packages from source.